# PhpMyAdmin The session id is too long and Session object destruction failed Warning Messages

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin

Here are the full warning messages:

> **Warning** in .\libraries\session.inc.php#101  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid
>   characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'
>
> **Backtrace**
>
> .\libraries\session.inc.php#101: session_start()
>   .\libraries\common.inc.php#352: require(.\libraries\session.inc.php)
>   .\index.php#12: require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)

and

> **Warning** in .\libraries\session.inc.php#122  session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed
>
> **Backtrace**
>
> .\libraries\session.inc.php#122: session_regenerate_id(boolean true)
>   .\libraries\common.inc.php#872: PMA_secureSession() .\index.php#12:
>   require_once(.\libraries\common.inc.php)

Got these errors on my PMA login page. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

The last time I logged in was 3 days ago and it was working fine. Now, after several times of attempting to log in (I have a password, by the way), I just can't. I didn't change anything in my PMA files at all.

Help, anyone?

Comment: delete browser cookies, restart browser, try again

Comment: I can't believe I didn't consider that. Thanks! Now it's fine again. :)

Comment: i suspect a corruption at your end, your browser sends invalid session id, PMA bitches

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the permission for session folder:

```
chmod 777 -R /var/lib/php/session
```

Answer (score 1):

Change permission for the folder `/var/tmp` on MacOs Sierra

Simple open your terminal run `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www` and you are good to go.